# Is it a good practice to pass object as a paramater than separate variables to a function?

Tags: java

Is it a good practice to pass object as a paramater than separate variable. I have a class below. Instead of passing separate paramaters to **calc** function, is it a good practice to create an object say **CalcFields** and store z,l,y, product,user and code in it and pass that object to calc function. My concern is this list of paramters may grow in future, say 5 more fields need to be passed

```
Class ABC{
   private test(Order o){
     String z = //some logic to evaluate z
     String y = // some logic to evaluate y
     int p = calc(z, y, o.getProduct(), o.getUser(), o.getCode())
   }
}


Class Calculate{
  public int calc(String a, String b, Product a, User b, String d){
     ..........
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `calc` function specialized for `Order` instances? Or is it a general method that does nothing have to do with such orders?

Comment: those logics(z,y,...) could be part of the Order object, or another intermediate Class (as, for example, a list strings storing those logics, if they can be from 0 to n), so you could easily pass just the reference to the class. This way, "calc"'s signature never changes, even if more params are in game

Answer (score 4):

Answer to your question is yes, especially in Java where the only way to provide a parameter by reference is by using an object and calling its methods.

Parameter by reference means the function may change the value of the variable outside the scope of the called function. If you're not using an object, those parameters are always sent by value, meaning that only a copy of the value is sent to the function/method and the variable used in the function call will not change.

[image] [image source](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/programming/passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-visual-explanation.php)

Both are important in programming, it just depends on what your function is supposed to do.

Moreover, using an object as an argument in a function call encapsulates the data that is related together anyways.

---

That said, a good class design will avoid grouping objects too deeply (the **screw** in the **piston** of the **engine** that is in the **car** in a **warehouse** might not be relevant to a car seller's inventory application). Prefer the bare minimum, but don't be afraid to make an object hold an other one either. Perfect balance does not exist, but imbalance does­. This is not a problem in your case, just something to keep in mind. The final goal being to write as little *readable* code as possible

A problem I see in your design though is that you are breaking the object to manipulate the data outside it. Hold the urge to break an object inside an other object and prefer declaring a method inside the first object to call it from the second.

In your example, it would be preferable to call `calc` directly from the `order` object and add parameters as needed.

```
Class ABC{
   private test(Order o){
     String z = //some logic to evaluate z
     String y = // some logic to evaluate y
     int p = o.calc(z, y)
   }
}


Class Order {
  public int calc(String a, String b){
        //Product, User and your code are already stored in this object anyways
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends, if you would only call your function like this: `calc(z, y, o.getProduct(), o.getUser(), o.getCode())`, then there is no point having 5 paramters and you should just use 3 parameters and pass the entire `o` object.

On the other hand, if you would want to pass different arguments as well, for example `calc(z, y, o.getProduct(), o.getUser(), "anotherString")`, the best practice is to have methods like this:

```
public int calc(String a, String b, ABC c) {
    return this.calc(a, b, c.getProduct(), c.getUser(), c.getCode());
}

public int calc(String a, String b, Product a, User b, String d) {
     //do the calculation here
}
```

The first function offers the convinience of passing only 1 parameter, while the second function offers the flexibility of passing different parameters.